# Create rule whose LHS is already defined

Tags: evaluation, scoping, rule

My question will be clearest if defined using an example. Consider the following code:

```
Func[k_]:=Block[{a},
   a[t_]:=t^k;
   {a[t]->a[t]}
];
```

However, calling `Func[2]` returns `{t^2 -> t^2}` when I want it to return `{a[t]->t^2}`.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Func[k_] := a[t] -> Block[{a}, a[t_] := t^k; a[t]]`?

Comment: `Func[k_] := Block[{a}, a[t_] := t^k;
   Return[{Defer[a[t]] -> a[t]}];]`?

Comment: @kglr I don't think so, try `a[t] /. Func[2]`.

Comment: @Kuba, good point. `ReleaseHold@Block[{a}, a[t_] := t^k; Return[{Hold[a[t]] -> a[t]}];]` works though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func1[k_] := ReleaseHold @ Block[{a}, a[t_] := t^k; {Hold[a[t]] -> a[t]}]
func2[k_] := Activate @ Block[{a}, a[t_] := t^k; {Inactive[a[t]] -> a[t]}]

func1[3]
```

> {a[t] -> t^3}

```
func2[3]
```

> {a[t] -> t^3}

```
a[t] /. func1[5]
```

> t^5

```
a[t] /. func2[x]
```

> t^x

Answer (score 4):

I suggest wrapping the LHS `a[t]` in the `Rule` you are trying to return in [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html):

```
Clear[func]
func[k_] := Block[{a},
   a[t_] := t^k;
   {HoldPattern[a[t]] -> a[t]}
 ]

func[2]
(* Out: {HoldPattern[a[t]] -> t^2} *)

a[t] /. func[5]
(* Out:  t^5 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could return pure functions instead:

```
pow[k_] := a -> Function[t, t^k]
```

Examples:

```
a[t] /. pow[5]
a[10] /. pow[x]
a[2] /. pow[3]
```

> t^5
>
> 10^x
>
> 8

Comment: Nice, but irrelevant to my case, since my example is a large simplification of my problem. I require an answer which is specific to my case.

Answer (score 1):

I leave the "answer" tag on kglr's answer, although I actually have a better way to do it that works also for non-function symbols. The way I do it is by extending kglr's answer using strings and the [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) function:

```
FixStringRuleHeads [rule_] := If[StringQ[rule[[1]]], 
                                 Rule[Hold@ToExpression[rule[[1]]], rule[[2]]],
                                 rule];

Func[k_] := ReleaseHold@Block[{a}, 
     a[t_] := t^k;
     FixStringRuleHeads /@ {"a[t]" -> a[t], "t" -> a[1], a2[t] -> a[2 t], a3 -> a[3]}
];
```

So the following input has the desired output:

```
In[2]:= {a[t], t, a2[t], a3} /. Func[3]

Out[2]= {t^3, 1, 8 t^3, 27}
```